Install python 3.7.9 on a virtual environment
I setup a virtual environment in y linux host and install python 3.7.9. After performing the install, i still see only 3.6.7 using python --version or python3 --version. Is there a way to fix this ?
Could any one please help ? I Performed installation of 3.7.9 using below steps in the virtual environment

mkdir -p /users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7/
cd /users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.7.9.tgz
cd Python-3.7.9
./configure --prefix /users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7 --with-ssl
make
make install
/users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip
/users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip-tools


did you activate the virutal environment using something like source venv/bin/activate?

did you try to use command python3.7 ? And pip3.7? Eventually you can try to use full path /users/cgwcns/data/software/python3.7/bin/python

btw: if Linux was installed with Python 3.6 then better don't remove it and don't replace it - because Linux may need it to run some functions - and when you remove/replace it then system may not work. Usually when you install Python 3.7then you should have commands python3.7 and pip3.7, And when you install Python 3.10 then you should have python3.10 and pip.3.10
